# Is *trotz + dative* avoided in academic writing (for the sake of style)?

Tags: usage, preposition, grammatical-case, style

I checked out the case-government issue of *trotz* in Duden's Richtige-und-Gutes-Deutsch and Langenscheidt-Großwörterbuch-Deutsch-als-Fremdsprache;
both references mark its dative government as colloquial and this stylistic issue has become a major concern :
I dare not use ,,trotz'' with the dative case, for fear that some day I would use it out of habit in academic writing, where colloquialism is definitely frowned upon;
so I'd like to request a clarification: should *trotz+ dative noun* be avoided in academic writing for the sake of style?

Comment: "trotz" + dative = colloquial - Agreed, but so commonly used nowadays (even in public media) that probably one of the next Duden releases will accept it as correct. "trotz" + genitive, on the other hand, has a slight touch of elitism to it, IMHO.

Comment: Nowadays, and in the 18th century. ;-)

Comment: Instead of putting the question on hold, why don't replace "Should be avoided" with "Is avoided", and then it becomes a question with a potential objective answer.  I've done so now.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer: I’m not sure this edit is a good idea anyway, but only changing the *title* so that it no longer corresponds to the actual question in the body is definitely nit the right way.

Comment: @chirlu Point taken re consistency.  So in the name of being constructive shall we change the question to similar one that can generate objective answers?

Comment: Es sind eher die Warum-Fragen die ätzen. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Formal writing seems decisively in favour of *trotz* + genitive, as it has been since the mid-19th century.

[image]

The larger dynamic here is that the use of SMS and the like have democratised writing a bit, therefore dialect (for example Swiss) and vernacular elements generally are being written a bit more.  But that is different than any shift in what is printed in formal writing.

And of course the firmly established *trotzdem* is based on the dative.

Comment: Wieso ist kein "trotz der" in der Grafik?

Comment: Weil die Oberflächenform "trotz der" sowohl Dativ wie Genitiv sein kann...  Sagt also nichts aus.  (Und weil ich n fauler Sack bin.)

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=trotz+der%2Ctrotz+dem%2Ctrotz+des&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctrotz%20der%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctrotz%20dem%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctrotz%20des%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Viele der „trotz dem“ Fundstellen sind Grammatikdiskussionen oder getrenntes „trotzdem“. Ich habe aber auch echten Dativ gefunden, sogar mit „-e“.

Comment: Wie gesagt, ich bin ein fauler Sack.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=trotz+dem+Regen%2Ctrotz+des+Regens&year_start=1700&year_end=1900&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctrotz%20dem%20Regen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctrotz%20des%20Regens%3B%2Cc0 + https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=trotz+dem+Krieg%2Ctrotz+des+Krieges+%2B+trotz+des+Kriegs&year_start=1700&year_end=1900&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctrotz%20dem%20Krieg%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28trotz%20des%20Krieges%20%2B%20trotz%20des%20Kriegs%29%3B%2Cc0 + etliche sonstige 3-Gramme